# How to show that the following matrices $A$ and $B$ are conjugate in the group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for certain values of $p$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I have the following matrices:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{, } B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Given a prime $p$, I want to know when it $A$ and $B$ are conjugate in the group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

(Specifically, I am tasked with showing that they are not conjugate for $p=5$ and are when $p=11$, and am curious as to when they are or are not in general.)

I have observed that $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & n\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and thus that $A^3 = B$, and that $A$ has order $p$. $B$ also has order $p$ unless $p=3$, so I can't use the fact that they must have the same order to eliminate any primes other than $3$.

What can I do to find out for which primes they are conjugate, and how could I systematically construct a matrix $P$ such that $B = P^{-1} A P$ when it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P^{-1}AP = B$ then $P$ is in the normalizer of the subgroup of upper unitriangular matrices, so $P$ is upper triangular, and in fact we can assume that $P$ is diagonal, so $P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}t&0\\0&t^{-1}\end{array}\right)$ for some $0 \ne t \in {\mathbb F}_p$,
and then we have$$P^{-1}AP = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&t^{-2}\\0&1\end{array}\right),$$
so $A$ and $B$ are conjugate if and only if $3$ is a square modulo $p$.

Comment: Yes, rather a serious typo!